# MVC Maximum request length exceeded

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC solution. There is an action in the solution:

```
public FileResult ExportPdf(string pdfHtml, string pdfIdentifier)
{  
}
```

when I submit the form my javascript initializes a hidden field **pdfHtml** with text data (html of current page in base64 format). So this field may be larger than 10mb.

```
function ExportPDF() {

    document.getElementById('pdfHtml').value = window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('Report').outerHTML)));
    document.getElementById('exportForm').submit();
}
```

When I do post, I have an error

> Exception: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: There was an exception
>   running the extensions specified in the config file. --->
>   System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded. at
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()

I know about configuration in web.config file. So I did so:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="1147483647"  executionTimeout="200" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3294967295" />
      </requestFiltering>
 </security>
</system.webServer>
```

But I still get this error. I have lost my head with this issue, and have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: What about setting `HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout ` property?

Comment: @Murali I set executionTimeout="200", it's the same

Comment: @Murali to be more exactly I had found error in my DNA. This error was generated by remoting service called in ExportPdf function, not in my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Add this into your webconfigue. Error will resolve.